# Get ElementRef to the children from lower levels

Tags: angular

I know I can use `@ViewChild` to get a reference to some child of current component:

```
@ViewChild('someInput') someInput: ElementRef;
```

And inside the `HTML` part:

```
<input #someInput />
```

But what if I wanted to get a reference for the same input but that is inside a component which stands couple levels "lower"?

```
<component1>
   <component2>
      <component3>
         <input #someInput />
      </component3>
   </component2>
</component1>
```

Suppose, we want to get a ref to `#someInput` inside `component1.ts`. Is it possible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use **@ContentChildren()** decorator.

https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/api/core/index/ContentChildren-decorator.html

Comment: This is probably what I'm looking for, but I can't make it working with my project... It is finding nothing - empty query result. But I will mark the answer as a correct one, because it definitely should solve my problem. Maybe I'm just using it in a wrong way.

Comment: use it in inside ngAfterContentInit

Comment: Aaaaaa, I was using it inside `ngAfterViewInit`. Now everything is working fine :) Thanks!!!